# IBM Host On Demand Macro <condition> description element

Tags: xml

Fairly new to coding and trying to optimize a macro I'm using at work.
I'm trying to create a macro, which given a number of variables, iterates trough the same action, for a user-specified number of times. My prior, non elegant way was to create 10 instances of the same "if/else" sequence and iterate trough those, but I'm trying to (1) shorten the code and (2) remove the restriction of 10 maximum iterations.

Trough reading manuals, I'm trying to set it up with only 3 screens and create a loop, so it goes back to the same screen if a certain condition isn't met, but I keep getting the same error I can't figure out.

My code:

```
<HAScript name="new label" description="" timeout="60000" pausetime="300" promptall="true" blockinput="true" author="nikbrems" creationdate="26 Jan 2022, 01:16:16" supressclearevents="false" usevars="true" ignorepauseforenhancedtn="true" delayifnotenhancedtn="0" ignorepausetimeforenhancedtn="true" continueontimeout="false">

<vars>
  <create name="$HU_Profile$" type="string" value="" />
  <create name="$Transit_Final_Dest$" type="string" value="" />
  <create name="$Copy_HPC$" type="string" value="" />
  <create name="$Label_Request$" type="integer" value="3" />
  <create name="$Label_Count$" type="integer" value="0" />
</vars>


<screen name="Screen1" entryscreen="true" exitscreen="false" transient="false">
    <description >
        <oia status="NOTINHIBITED" optional="false" invertmatch="false" />
    </description>
    <actions>
        <prompt name="&apos;Labels Required&apos;" description="" row="10" col="15" len="1" default="" clearfield="true" encrypted="false" movecursor="true" xlatehostkeys="false" assigntovar="$Label_Request$" varupdateonly="true" required="true" title="" />
        <prompt name="&apos;HU Profile&apos;" description="" row="11" col="215" len="9" default="" clearfield="true" encrypted="false" movecursor="true" xlatehostkeys="false" assigntovar="$HU_Profile$" varupdateonly="true" required="true" title="" />
        <prompt name="&apos;Transit &amp; Final Dest&apos;" description="" row="12" col="015" len="9" default="" clearfield="true" encrypted="false" movecursor="true" xlatehostkeys="false" assigntovar="$Transit_Final_Dest$" varupdateonly="true" required="true" title="" />
        <prompt name="&apos;Copy HPC&apos;" description="" row="13" col="15" len="11" default="" clearfield="true" encrypted="false" movecursor="true" xlatehostkeys="false" assigntovar="$Copy_HPC$" varupdateonly="true" required="true" title="" />
    </actions>
    <nextscreens timeout="0" >
        <nextscreen name="Screen2" />
    </nextscreens>
</screen>

<screen name="Screen2" entryscreen="false" exitscreen="false" transient="false">
    <description uselogic="(1 and 2)">
        <oia status="NOTINHIBITED" optional="false" invertmatch="false" />
    <condition $Label_Request$!=$Label_Count$ />
    </condition>
    </description>
    <actions>
              <varupdate name="$Label_Count$" value="$Label_Count$+1" />
              <input value="&apos;[pf10]&apos;" row="0" col="0" movecursor="true" xlatehostkeys="true" encrypted="false" />
              <input value="$HU_Profile$" row="4" col="25" movecursor="true" xlatehostkeys="true" encrypted="false" />
              <input value="$Transit_Final_Dest$" row="4" col="70" movecursor="true" xlatehostkeys="true" encrypted="false" />
              <input value="$Copy_HPC$" row="7" col="27" movecursor="true" xlatehostkeys="true" encrypted="false" />
              <input value="&apos;N&apos;" row="6" col="70" movecursor="true" xlatehostkeys="true" encrypted="false" />
              <input value="&apos;[enter]&apos;" row="0" col="0" movecursor="true" xlatehostkeys="true" encrypted="false" />
              <input value="&apos;[pf12]&apos;" row="0" col="0" movecursor="true" xlatehostkeys="true" encrypted="false" />
    </actions>
    <nextscreens timeout="0" >
        <nextscreen name="Screen3" />
    </nextscreens>
</screen>

<screen name="Screen3" entryscreen="false" exitscreen="true" transient="false">
    <description uselogic="(1 and 2)">
        <oia status="NOTINHIBITED" optional="false" invertmatch="false" />
    <condition $Label_Request$!=$Label_Count$ />
    </condition>
    </description>
    <actions>
        
        <message title="&apos;END&apos;" value="$Label_Count$+&apos; labels created for &apos;+$HU_Profile$" />
        
    </actions>
    <nextscreens timeout="0" >
    </nextscreens>
    <recolimit value="10000" />
</screen>
</HAScript>
```

I keep getting error *Element type "condition" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".* and I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. Manuals aren't helping and I can't find an example of the condition element being used, to see what I'm doing wrong. Anyone got a clue?

Comment: Found it! 

Instead of `<condition $Label_Request$!=$Label_Count$ />` it should have been `<condition value="$Label_Request$!=$Label_Count$" optional="false" invertmatch="false" />`

Comment: You're allowed to post an answer to your own question.  It seems like a well-written question so perhaps consider it.

Answer (score 0):

Found it!

Instead of `<condition $Label_Request$!=$Label_Count$ />`
it should have been `<condition value="$Label_Request$!=$Label_Count$" optional="false" invertmatch="false" />`